# Wordpress Ajax Call Using Link Class As Filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

So, I've got an ordered list that I'd like to use to pull posts via ajax into a separate container.  I know how to pull Ajax regularly, with any link, but what I'm trying to accomplish is utilize the list item ID as a filter for the ajax pull.

So, here's an example of the list:

```
<ul>
<li class="user" id="1">Thana</li>
<li class="user" id="2">Jim</li>
<li class="user" id="3">Tom</li>
<li class="user" id="4">Sam</li>
</ul>
```

In that list, the class identifies the kind of meta data being pulled which in this case, the class user would relate to the User Id of an author and then the ID of the list item would be their user ID.

What I'm wanting is for you to click on a list item and then have Ajax pull all posts by that user ID and return the content into a div called #posts-grid.

I'm assuming that I'd have to set up a variable somehow prior to the Ajax call, but I'm not all that great in that area of jQuery/Javascript - but then again, maybe I'm not even on the right track with that thought either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.user').click(function(){
        var userID = $(this).attr('id');  
        getUser(userID);
    });

    function getUser(ID){
         $.ajax({
             url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
           data: {
              id: ID,
              action: "get_user_posts"
           },
           type: 'POST',
           error: function() {
              console.log('error');
           },
           success: function(data) {
              //do something with the return data and place it in post-grid
           }
        });    
    }
});
```

In your functions.php file you can register the function that is called by ajax:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_user_posts', 'get_user_posts_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_user_posts', 'get_user_posts_callback');

function get_user_posts_callback(){
    $id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    //echo result
    die('');
}
```

You can use the returned data in javascript to place it inside your #post-grid div.

Comment: How would I style the posts doing it this way? Would it be in the functions area?

Comment: What I usually do is returni the data that I need from functions.php in an Array converted to JSON using json_encode() in php. In javascript you encode the return value to a javascript Object using jQuery.parseJSON(). After that I build the post as an html string and append it using jQuery